# "Too many fields defined" when querying Excel using ADO

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ado, adodb

I'm querying an Excel 2010 workbook using the following ADO:

```
Function WorksheetRecordsetSQL(workbookPath As String, sheetName As String, selectSQL As String) As ADODB.Recordset

Dim objconnection As New ADODB.Connection
Dim objrecordset As New ADODB.Recordset

Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const adCmdText = &H1

objconnection.CommandTimeout = 99999999

objconnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & workbookPath & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";"

objrecordset.Open selectSQL, _
    objconnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

Set WorksheetRecordsetSQL = objrecordset

End Function
```

When I call it with this SQL:

```
Select * FROM [someWorksheet$]
```

the function executes successfully.  But if I call it with:

```
Select *,cdate(someField) FROM [someWorksheet$]
```

then I get this error:

```
Too many fields defined.
```

I found that the `select *` query was producing a recordset with 255 fields (the maximum that the Access engine can have in a query), even though there are only 58 columns in the sheet.  So that one extra `cdate()` column overloaded the engine and produced the error.

Is there a way that I can keep a `select *` query from picking up blank columns from an Excel sheet?  Or some parameters that I can set that will allow more than 255 fields?

Comment: Have you tried by setting `HDR=False`?

Comment: I can´t se why you would want to fetch "someFields twice ? If you only want the "someField" then write: "Select cdate(someField) FROM [someWorksheet$]"

Comment: @carleson, I need to fetch `someField` separately because ADO is detecting its datatype as text, so `12/13/35` is being read literally as a string rather than as `12/13/1935`.  So I also need to select it cast as date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can **specify the range** which should be read and so **reduce the number of columns entering into the query**. Here from cell A1 to column BF (58) all rows:

> FROM [Source_sheet$A1:BF]

```
Sub main()
    Dim reultingRecordset As ADODB.Recordset

    Set reultingRecordset = WorksheetRecordsetSQL( _
        "C:\Temp\VBA\ReadWithADOSource.xlsx", _
        "Source_sheet", _
        "Select * FROM [Source_sheet$]")

    Debug.Print "Select * FROM [Source_sheet$] >"
    Debug.Print "Fields: " & reultingRecordset.Fields.Count & " Records: " & reultingRecordset.RecordCount

    Set reultingRecordset = WorksheetRecordsetSQL( _
        "C:\Temp\VBA\ReadWithADOSource.xlsx", _
        "Source_sheet", _
        "Select *,cdate(Col2) FROM [Source_sheet$A1:BF]")

    Debug.Print "Select *,cdate(Col2) FROM [Source_sheet$A1:BC] > "
    Debug.Print "Fields: " & reultingRecordset.Fields.Count & " Records: " & reultingRecordset.RecordCount

End Sub
```

**Output:**

Select * FROM [Source_sheet$] >
Fields: 255 Records: 8

Select *,cdate(Col2) FROM [Source_sheet$A1:BC] >
Fields: 59 Records: 8

Comment: Outstanding.  This also solves another issue that I was encountering with the field names not being given until several rows down into the sheet; `select * from [source_sheet$a4:bc]` accomplishes this nicely.